# Titanium Studio_not recognising any attached device

Tags: titanium, device, appcelerator, titanium-modules

After two weeks of openning it, it doesn't recognise any attached device (tried with two different devices and genymotion plugin). Wokring on windows machine.

Comment: Provide some code example showing what you are trying to achieve and where is an issue.

Comment: it is not a programming error but downloading android 2.3.3. helped. will write it down in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading android 2.3.3, not really sure what is the trick there, just found that recommendations after hours of googling